# how to get authenticate using wsdl2ruby

Tags: ruby, web-services, wsdl2ruby

I am connecting to a web service using the wsdl2ruby.  To access the functions in the webservice I need to authenticate. In ruby how to authenticate with username and password in wsdl2ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the constructor of your RPC Driver Class:

self.options["protocol.http.basic_auth"] << [endpoint_url, user, password]